# Drupal Nodes shows 404 when it exists

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Some nodes are showing a 404 status when they exist in the database. You also get a 404 if you type in the url to edit that node in the admin page.

These nodes are being created in an automated fashion in the database, from CSV files. What I'd like to ask is which db fields would trigger a 404 on a node?

I have checked the url_alias table, and the nodes have valid entries. ie: If I enter example.com/node/512682 in the URL, it will do a redirect to the SEF url, but that would show a 404

Comment: Are you sure they are published?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your 'code creation from CSV' automation also creates entries in the 'node_revisions' table? If it doesn't, this would explain the 404s - even if you have disabled revisions for a node type, Drupal will still expect at least one entry per node there.

You can create those on your import as well, but I agree with Scott Reynen (+1) that you should probably use `node_save()` to ensure proper processing of newly created nodes (especially invocation of the related hooks) to prevent other surprises as well.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. Some of the entries were missing corresponding entries in node_revisions. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up with the same problem without any migration/import being involved. Believe it came from an incomplete/corrupt save that took place. I've tried using a View Bulk Operation page to trigger a node save... but no luck I'm stuck with at least one node that's stuck in a time rift.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your import is flawed, but it's hard to know without more information. Did you use [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_save)? If not, you should try that. If that still doesn't work, trying looking at the $node object immediately after node_save() and see if it has a new nid value. If not, you're not passing the right info to node_save(). If you do get a new nid value and the node still won't load, I'd start looking at modules that might be breaking Drupal. But I'd put my money on switching to node_save() solving the problem.

Comment: Thats a great suggestion. I may look into that eventually as I take it would trigger the hooks that may be needed by extensions...

Answer (score 1):

Check the query that is being run. We had the same problem and it turned out the importer was creating the entries with a uid that did not exist. When querying Drupal made a join with the user table and that came back empty.

```
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.language, n.uid, n.status, n.created, n.changed, n.comment,
n.promote, n.moderate, n.sticky, n.tnid, n.translate, r.vid, r.uid AS revision_uid,
r.title, r.body, r.teaser, r.log, r.timestamp AS revision_timestamp, r.format, u.name,
u.picture, u.data FROM node n INNER JOIN users u ON u.uid = n.uid INNER JOIN
node_revisions r ON r.vid = n.vid WHERE n.nid = <some-number>
```

You can find out for sure using the devel module. Point it to the URL you think should be showing a module and look at the queries it creates.